# @SqsListener analog in 2.0 java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

After doing some research couldn't find an analog for @SqsListener in 2.0 java SDK. I plan to subscribe to the s3 event and executing RecieveMessaheRequest requests periodically seems overcomplicated compared to SDK  1.X approach with annotation.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/sqs.adoc#sample-listener-application) does not look very complicated, if you share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it would be easier